# How to validate if cucumber tags are valid or not

Tags: typescript, cucumber

We are using cucumber through APIs, where we create a cucumber config with featureFile Path and the tags. I want to throw an error before the tests even begin to execute to see if any tests were found with the provided tags or not.

Is it possible to do so? I could parse all feature files and check but that seems like a bad solution - both runtime and design wise.